# Undesired result if condition

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

Below is the file on which I am applying the below unix script.

```
    0.30 2.30 - - - - - - -
    2.30 3.30 - - NA NA - - -
    3.30 4.30 - - NA NA - - -
    4.30 5.30 - - - - - - -
    5.30 6.30 - - NA NA - - -
    6.30 0.30 - - - - - - -

##Time=`echo $(date) | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'` 
Time=05;
Result="False";
while [[ "${Result}" != "True" ]]
do
    while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
    do
        if [[ "${Time}" -ge "${f1}" && "${Time}" -le "${f2}" ]]
        then 
                echo $Time is between $f1 $f2 True
                Result="True";
        else
                echo $Time is between $f1 $f2 False
        fi
    done < consolidated.txt
done
```

I am getting the below result: Please notice that the if condition is being satisfied twice. 05 is not between 5.30 and 6.30 still it returns true.
What am I missing here.

```
05 is between 0.30 2.30 False
05 is between 2.30 3.30 False
05 is between 3.30 4.30 False
05 is between 4.30 5.30 True
05 is between 5.30 6.30 True
05 is between 6.30 0.30 False
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: this is a script in ksh

Comment: We have a tag for that. You need to include all these important details when you first post the question.

Comment: Note that your test using the symmetric condition `time >= start && time <= end` leads to the problem that 5.30 would be part of both the 4.30 - 5.30 and 5.30 - 6.30 time ranges.  It is usually best to use an asymmetric condition like `time >= start && time < end` instead when the ranges are set up contiguously as in the data.  This is an open-closed interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various issues are visible:

- The outer loop in your code is problematic.  If none of the time ranges in `consolidated.txt` matches, `${Result}` remains `False` and the outer loop never terminates.
- The last time range in the data, `6.30 0.30` is never going to match anything because the end of the range is smaller numerically than the start of the range.
- With your condition using `time >= start && time <= end`, if the time value is `5.30` then that is going to match both the `4.30 5.30` range (it is equal to the end time) and the `5.30 6.30` range (it is equal to the start time).

Unlike Bash, Korn shell does support floating point arithmetic, which is useful.

Instead of the `[[ … ]]` and using string comparisons (`-ge`, `-le`), you should use `(( … ))` and (floating point) numeric comparisons (`>=`, `<`).

Assembling these changes into a single script, and ignoring the `Result` variable since it isn't relevant here, you get:

```
#!/bin/ksh

for Time in 0 3 05 5.30 7.00
do
    while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
    do
        if (( "${Time}" >= "${f1}" && "${Time}" < "${f2}" ))
        then echo "${Time} is between ${f1} and ${f2} True"
        else echo "${Time} is between ${f1} and ${f2} False"
        fi
    done << EOF
    0.30 2.30 - - - - - - -
    2.30 3.30 - - NA NA - - -
    3.30 4.30 - - NA NA - - -
    4.30 5.30 - - - - - - -
    5.30 6.30 - - NA NA - - -
    6.30 24.00 - - - - - - -
EOF
done
```

Yes, the `EOF` at the end of the here document does need to be in the left margin.  You could use `<<-'EOF'` and indent the end marker `EOF` as long as the indentation is tabs, not blanks.

The output from this script is:

```
0 is between 0.30 and 2.30 False
0 is between 2.30 and 3.30 False
0 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
0 is between 4.30 and 5.30 False
0 is between 5.30 and 6.30 False
0 is between 6.30 and 24.00 False
3 is between 0.30 and 2.30 False
3 is between 2.30 and 3.30 True
3 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
3 is between 4.30 and 5.30 False
3 is between 5.30 and 6.30 False
3 is between 6.30 and 24.00 False
05 is between 0.30 and 2.30 False
05 is between 2.30 and 3.30 False
05 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
05 is between 4.30 and 5.30 True
05 is between 5.30 and 6.30 False
05 is between 6.30 and 24.00 False
5.30 is between 0.30 and 2.30 False
5.30 is between 2.30 and 3.30 False
5.30 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
5.30 is between 4.30 and 5.30 False
5.30 is between 5.30 and 6.30 True
5.30 is between 6.30 and 24.00 False
7.00 is between 0.30 and 2.30 False
7.00 is between 2.30 and 3.30 False
7.00 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
7.00 is between 4.30 and 5.30 False
7.00 is between 5.30 and 6.30 False
7.00 is between 6.30 and 24.00 True
```

If you change the `<` condition to `<=`, which is equivalent to what the question uses, then you get the output:

```
…
5.30 is between 3.30 and 4.30 False
5.30 is between 4.30 and 5.30 True
5.30 is between 5.30 and 6.30 True
5.30 is between 6.30 and 24.00 False
…
```

With the last range left as `6.30 0.30`, the final part of the output would look like:

```
…
7.00 is between 5.30 and 6.30 False
7.00 is between 6.30 and 0.30 False
```

Comment: Thank you very much for differentiating between the [[...]] and ((...)) for string and numeric comparisons. I have edited the script and it seems to be working fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is due to the line `Time=05;`  ksh is not interpreting this as a floating point value. `let` will force it to do so.

```
$ Time=05;echo $Time
05
$ let Time=05;echo $Time
5
```

Another common idiom is `Time=$(echo $Time |bc)`

Here is an alternative phrasing for your logic:

```
$echo $Time $f1 $f2
05 5.30 6.30
$
$let Time=05     
$ if [[ (( $Time > $f1 )) && (( $Time < $f2 )) ]]
> then 
>        echo $Time is between $f1 $f2 True
> else
>        echo $Time is between $f1 $f2 False
>fi    
5 is between 5.30 6.30 False
```

The `(( ... ))` is a numeric conditional similar to `[[ ... ]]` 
It is designed for use in `if` and `while` constructs.

You can find more details [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_02.htm) in section 6.2.2 of Learning the Korn Shell.